# Concatenate column names by using the binary values in the columns

Tags: python, pandas

Currently, I have a dataframe as follows:

```
date          A    B   C
02/19/2020    0    0   0 
02/20/2020    0    0   0
02/21/2020    1    1   1
02/22/2020    0    1   0
02/23/2020    0    1   1
02/24/2020    0    0   1
02/25/2020    1    0   1
02/26/2020    1    0   0
```

The binary columns contain integers. The "date" column is a DateTime object. I want to create a new categorical column that is based on the binary columns as follows

```
date          A    B   C   new
02/19/2020    0    0   0   "None"
02/20/2020    0    0   0   "None"
02/21/2020    1    1   1   A+B+C
02/22/2020    0    1   0   B
02/23/2020    0    1   1   B+C
02/24/2020    0    0   1   C
02/25/2020    1    0   1   A+C
02/26/2020    1    0   0   A
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) for matrix multiplication  with columns names with omit first column by position in [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), add separator to columns names without first and last remove separator by indexing `str[:-1]`:

```
df['new'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].dot(df.columns[1:] + '+').str[:-1]
#set empty string to None
df.loc[df['new'].eq(''), 'new'] = None
print (df)
         date  A  B  C    new
0  02/19/2020  0  0  0   None
1  02/20/2020  0  0  0   None
2  02/21/2020  1  1  1  A+B+C
3  02/22/2020  0  1  0      B
4  02/23/2020  0  1  1    B+C
5  02/24/2020  0  0  1      C
6  02/25/2020  1  0  1    A+C
7  02/26/2020  1  0  0      A
```

If possible use `NaN`s instead `None`s:

```
df['new'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].dot(df.columns[1:] + '+').str[:-1].replace('', np.nan)

print (df)
         date  A  B  C    new
0  02/19/2020  0  0  0    NaN
1  02/20/2020  0  0  0    NaN
2  02/21/2020  1  1  1  A+B+C
3  02/22/2020  0  1  0      B
4  02/23/2020  0  1  1    B+C
5  02/24/2020  0  0  1      C
6  02/25/2020  1  0  1    A+C
7  02/26/2020  1  0  0      A
```

Or if possible set first column to `DatetimeIndex` use:

```
df1 = df.set_index('date')
df1['new'] = df1.dot(df1.columns + '+').str[:-1]
df1.loc[df1['new'].eq(''), 'new'] = None
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the Dataframe to calculate the new columns values and then add it.

This is a basic example

```
new_column = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    row_val = None

    if row["A"]:
       if row_val:
          row_val += "+A"
       else:
          row_val = "A"

    if row["B"]:
       if row_val:
          row_val += "+B"
       else:
          row_val = "B"

    if row["C"]:
       if row_val:
          row_val += "+C"
       else:
          row_val = "C"
    
    if row_val is None:
       row_val = "None"
    
    new_column.append(row_val)

df["new_column_name"] = new_column
```